# How to pass an object to a method in Scala

Tags: scala, methods, singleton

How can I pass the reference of an object to method in Scala? E.g. I want this to compile

```
object Constants {
  val constantA:Double = ???
}


def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], Constants) = ??? // does not compile
def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], constants:Constants) = ??? // does not compile
```

Of course I can just reference `Constants` without passing it through the argument list, but I would prefer to list pass all dependencies of the method explicitly as arguments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Constants` is an object. You don't specify objects as parameter types for method parameters, you specify *types* as parameter types for method parameters:

```
def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], constants: Constants.type) = ???
```

Generally speaking, more precise types are good, but in this case, it might be overdoing it with an *overly precise* type, since there is exactly one instance of the type `Constants.type`, so you cannot ever pass anything other than the `Constants` object as an argument, which makes the whole idea of "parameterizing" rather pointless.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware that it does not make much sense from a OO perspective, but sometimes I'd like to design my methods to acts as pure functions where I'd like to pass all input data in the argument list.

Comment: @j You have a very valid point here. I found myself having to do that as well in some circonstances. I guess the rational maybe is that not one size fit all. There might be corner case where that might make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Any type

```
def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], constants: Any)
```

but this wouldn't allow you to access the constantA value. Alternatively you could define a trait with the constant and let you object implement that:

```
trait ConstantA {
  val constantA:Double
}

object Constant extends ConstantA {
  override val constantA:Double = 0.0
}

def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], constants: ConstantA) {
   ...
   // use constants.constantA
   println(constants.constantA)
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jörg W Mittag's answer, you can create an interface:

```
trait IConstants {
  def constantA: Double
}

object Constants extends IConstants {
  val constantA: Double = ???
}

def calc(numbers:Seq[Double], constants: IConstants) = ???
```

Whether this is useful very much depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Which way would be more "idiomatic"?

Comment: I think the last paragraph of Jörg's answer should tell you that: allowing _only_ `Constants` isn't a useful thing to do :) But both ways are idiomatic enough.

Comment: How would you pass the object to the calc()?

Comment: @b15 `calc(someSeq, Constants)`.

Answer (score -3):

Look at the synthax of your method definition: what does your calc method produce ? Unit ? Int  ? I suggest that  you review the basics of the Scala synthax  first

Comment: I think I'm well aware of the basics of the Scala syntax. The return value of a method is automatically infered by the scala compiler. Or what do you exactly want to say with your answer?